# The slice filtration does not arise from a $t$-structure

Tags: equivariant-homotopy, slice-filtration

I've heard this argument quite a bit that the slice filtration does not arise from a $t$-structure on the category of genuine $G$-spectra. Mike Hill points out in Remark 3.12 of [The Equivariant Slice Filtration: a Primer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.3582) that desuspension does not always take $\tau_{\ge n}$ to $\tau_{\ge n-1}$. Therefore the slice filtration is certainly not arising from a $t$-structure where the translation functor is suspension/desuspension.

My question is probably very naïve, but do we know that there is no other endofunctor $T:\operatorname{Sp}^{g.G}\to\operatorname{Sp}^{g.G}$ which acts as a translation functor on the category of genuine $G$-spectra, so that $\tau_{\ge n} = T^n(\operatorname{Sp}^{g.G})$?

Comment: Corollary 4.24 of Hill-Hopkins-Ravenel states that smashing with a regular $G$-representation sphere $S^{k \rho_G}$ induces an equivalence from the category of slice $n$-positive $G$-spectra to slice $(n+k|G|)$-positive $G$-spectra. This isn't a shift by exactly one, so it doesn't affirm or deny the existence of a $t$-structure.